# Why does my gem work when installed from RubyGems.org, but not Github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, capistrano

I'm trying to extract a couple of tasks into a gem, but cannot get the code to load in my Capfile. The code is at: https://github.com/floydj/capistrano-mysql_tables.

In my Gemfile:

```
gem "capistrano-mysql_tables", github: "floydj/capistrano-mysql_tables"
```

In my Capfile:

```
require "capistrano/mysql_tables"
```

After `bundle install`, it seems to be good, but running `cap -T` results in:

```
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/mysql_tables
```

What is wrong with the code in the gem? I've looked at other Capistrano plugins and have tried to imitate them, but it always gives this error and I've run out of things to try. It appears to be some kind of path problem, maybe. Here's what I see with `gem contents`:

```
$ bundle exec gem contents capistrano-mysql_tables
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-d1b60186a06b/Gemfile
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-d1b60186a06b/Gemfile.lock
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-d1b60186a06b/LICENSE.txt
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-d1b60186a06b/README.md
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-d1b60186a06b/Rakefile
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-d1b60186a06b/bin/console
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-d1b60186a06b/bin/setup
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-d1b60186a06b/capistrano-mysql_tables.gemspec
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-d1b60186a06b/lib/capistrano-mysql_tables.rb
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-d1b60186a06b/lib/capistrano/mysql_tables.rb
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-d1b60186a06b/lib/capistrano/mysql_tables/version.rb
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-d1b60186a06b/lib/capistrano/tasks/mysql_tables.rake
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-d1b60186a06b/test/capistrano/mysql_tables_test.rb
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-d1b60186a06b/test/test_helper.rb
```

**Update:**

After fixing the mistake found by @Alex, it still didn't work. However, I decided to push the gem to RubyGems, and then install via Gemfile in the standard way:

`gem "capistrano-mysql_tables"`

And after the standard install command, it works fine. But why does it work now? I suppose it has something to do with paths, the contents now list the following:

```
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-0.0.2/Gemfile
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-0.0.2/Gemfile.lock
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-0.0.2/LICENSE.txt
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-0.0.2/README.md
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-0.0.2/Rakefile
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-0.0.2/bin/console
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-0.0.2/bin/setup
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-0.0.2/capistrano-mysql_tables.gemspec
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-0.0.2/lib/capistrano-mysql_tables.rb
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-0.0.2/lib/capistrano/mysql_tables.rb
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-0.0.2/lib/capistrano/mysql_tables/version.rb
/Users/username/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/gems/capistrano-mysql_tables-0.0.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/mysql_tables.rake
```

I'm glad I got it working, but would like to know why it failed before? Any ideas?

Comment: you don't have `mysql_tables.rake` file. load the file that you have: `load File.expand_path('../tasks/table_sync.rake', __FILE__)`

Comment: @Alex - good point. I've corrected that, but still am getting the same `cannot load such file` error from the Capfile.

Comment: I dont think `cap -T` is executed through bundler so then only regularily installed gems is available.  maybe `bundle exec cap -T` works..

Comment: I know rubygems has a special handling of gems containing dashes, I encountered issues a long time ago : https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/pull/3195
So it could actually be a bug on rubygems

Comment: Maybe it's something to do with this "Note that because RubyGems lacks the ability to handle gems from git, any gems installed from a git repository will not show up in gem list. They will, however, be available after running Bundler.setup." https://bundler.io/guides/git.html#:~:text=Note%20that%20because%20RubyGems%20lacks%20the%20ability%20to%20handle%20gems%20from%20git%2C%20any%20gems%20installed%20from%20a%20git%20repository%20will%20not%20show%20up%20in%20gem%20list.%20They%20will%2C%20however%2C%20be%20available%20after%20running%20Bundler.setup.